# how can I distinguish from detail_page to the list_page?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How can I distinguish the

I have a Vue project, when I from list_page go to its detail_page, then I can use the `this.$router.go(-1)` to go back to the list_page.

and I can from other_pages to the the list_page, but how can I distinguish  the two ways to the list_page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a `router.push()` with query parameters.

`` this. $router.push({ name: 'list-page-name`, query: { fromRoute: this. $route.name} ``

Now on the list-page you can get source from `this.$route.query.fromRoute`

Answer (score 0):

You can use router.push method like router.push('/path-string'). Here path-string will be from 'router.js' where you have defined all routers. This method will change current route path.